# head outputting text on single line without linebreaks

Tags: bash, shell, head

My command is this:

```
df=$(echo `df -h | head -3`)
echo $df
```

I would expect it to display the first three lines of `df -h` output as such:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/abc/asdf       16G   5.6G  9.4G  38% /
abcd            1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
```

Instead, it outputs this:

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on /abc/asdf 16G 5.6G 9.4G 38% / abcd 1.9G 12K 1.9G 1% /dev
```

- How can I make sure that `echo $df` outputs the newline character in my shell script?
- What is causing the echo to ignore the newline character from `head`?

Comment: Why do you think it's only outputting the first two line? I see the header line, `/`, and `/dev`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I misread my own output. I have edited my post to reflect the real issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote the variable to prevent word splitting:

```
echo "$df"
```

99% of the time you should quote variables when you use them. Only use variables unquoted if you really want them to be subject to word splitting and globbing. There are some occasions where quotes are not needed (e.g. assignments like `a=$b`), but the redundant quotes won't hurt.

I just notieced that you're also using `echo` inside the `$()`. I'm not sure why, but you also need quotes there:

```
df=$(echo "`df -h | head -3`")
```

But you don't need echo, you can just write:

```
df=$(df -h | head -3)
```

Comment: @bvpx use __df=$(df -h | head -3)__

Comment: I see that, I put it in my answer.

Comment: When you first posted the comment, I thought you were just changing `$(` to backticks, then I saw what you actually wrote so I deleted my comment.

Comment: @bvpx do you change the FS variable?

Comment: @طاهر I went with `df=$(df -h | head -3)` since it was the most simple and elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need setup IFS variable.

```
$ df=$(IFS=$''; echo `df -h | head -3`)
$ echo $df
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3        15G  4.2G  9.7G  31% /
devtmpfs       1010M     0 1010M   0% /dev
$
```